# Scroll View not showing all the views in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I am unable to see the top most views under ScrollView. 
I had placed the scrollview under Relative layout. ScrollView has a child layout i.e. Linear layout which has some series of buttons.
Problem is that i am unable to see the top most views which are present in the ScrollView.

Below is the layout xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#217d27"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="backPressed"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Heading Text"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:onClick="homeButtonClicked"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Button 1"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 2"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 3"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 4"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 5"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 6"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 7"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 8"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 9"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 10"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 11"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 12"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please see the screen shot for reference.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Use Relative layout instead of linear as parent.

Comment: Nope Relative layout is also not working. I am getting the same result.

Comment: your code is 99% perfect just remove 1 line only see my answer i update your code dude and u welcome always :)

Comment: I shouldn't have used this in Linear Layout android:layout_gravity="center".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just remove this line in linear layout which is direct child of scroll view 
  android:layout_gravity="center"  try this code which is updated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#217d27"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="backPressed"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Heading Text"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:onClick="homeButtonClicked"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Button 1"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 2"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 3"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 4"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 5"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 6"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 7"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 8"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 9"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 10"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 11"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button 12"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

Just change the `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Give the `android:layout_gravity="top|center"` instead of `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

This values helped me solve a similar problem:
Set android:fillViewport="true" on the ScrollView
and use  android:**gravity** instead of  android:**layout_gravity** on the ScrollView child, in my case a LinearLayout with all weights cleared.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the parent layout to Linear. It might work. Don't know how and why, but for me it worked in a similar situation. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Give a top padding of 50dp

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Comment: temporary solution, like "Jugaad"

Answer (score -1):

use android:layout_gravity="center" in LinearLayout

Answer (score -1):

```
it's work 100% 

 1. LinearLayout ->
    2. ScrollView-> 

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".sales.CustomerDetailListActivity">
       <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/layoutCard"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subtitle_of_page"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            android:fadingEdge="none">
</ScrollView>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).